# Which registry keys are impacted with Xerox Printer driver installation?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, windows-registry

I am implementing a driver deployment with Samba.  Every possible model of printer found an easy solution, except for Xerox Workcenter.

After browsing the Internet, I found that Xerox printer driver has to change some registry keys in order to work, keys which are changed by the executable downloadable on the manufacturer website.  Do you know which key are impacted by the Xerox Workcenter GPD driver?

This corresponds to the error message I get while uploading to Samba, which asks the position of a file named as a registry key.

I browse Samba bug tracker and they did not specify which registry key are impacted.

I contacted Xerox itself, but despite that fact that we have a support contract and really a huge number of workstations, it seems that Xerox is not willing to help us.

Comment: I have used the freesoftware http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/ to see that there was a big impact on the windows registry.  In addition, some files are deleted after the installation process making it dificult to transmit the driver throught SMB.

Answer (score 1):

#### Which registry keys are impacted with Xerox Printer driver installation?

You can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Microsoft's [SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) to monitor registry changes.

1. Start Process Monitor.
2. Log results to a log file.
3. Install Xerox Printer Driver.
4. Stop logging.
5. Look at the log file for registry changes.

---

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous logging to a file, and much more.

Source [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: @MUYBelgium Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft offers a tool called [Attack Surface Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24487) that you can use to find this out. While it is intended to aid finding security-sensitive changes, it can find others too. It is a free download. I've had the best success running it on Win7, though it should support other OSes too.

What you do is start with a clean system (with ASA installed), and run one scan. This is the "baseline" scan. Then, install the program (or, in this case, driver) that will make changes to the system. Once the system is in the post-install state that you want to look at (i.e. after you first install the driver, or after you reboot post install, or after you configure an actual printer using the driver... or at more than one of these points) run ASA again and do a new scan. Then use ASA to generate a report that compares the new scan to the baseline scan. Registry changes (among many other things) will be in the report. If you do more than two scans, you can also compare them against one another to see the changes that are made from one scan to the next.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the GPL program Regshot that can point modification to registry, see explanation http://www.howtogeek.com/198679/how-to-use-regshot-to-monitor-your-registry/ and download http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/ .